# "Combined" difference / intersection of 3 or more strings

Tags: ruby, linux, algorithm, difference

[UPDATED QUESTION]
I am using a service that converts speech to text.

The service returns 3 alternative suggestions for a sentence e.g.

```
[ 
  "News update I read a Jones, near record snowfalls...",
  "News update I'm Rita Jones, near record snowfalls...",
  "News update I am Rita Jones, near record snow-falls..."
]
```

I want to be able to allow the user to choose the best bits from each of the sentences.

Parts of the sentence that are the same in all 3 alternatives should be presented as a single item, as there is no choice to be made:

```
["News", "Update", ...]
```

Parts of the sentence that differ should be presented as array, as there IS a choice to be made:

```
[["I", "I'm", "I am"], ["read a", "Rita"]]
```

The final output would look like this:

```
[
  ["News"],
  ["update"],
  ["I", "I'm", "I am"],
  ["read a", "Rita"],
  ["Jones,"],
  ["near"],
  ["record"],
  ["snowfalls", "snow-balls"]
]
```

Although the following is also acceptable:

```
[
  ["News update"],
  ["I", "I'm", "I am"],
  ["read a", "Rita"],
  ["Jones, near record"],
  ["snowfalls", "snow-balls"]
]
```

diff/wdiff might have the answer but I couldn't get anywhere.

I'm using Ruby but also happy with any Linux command line tool.

Comment: How the algorithm is supposed to know that "I'm" should be matched together with "I am", but not with "I read"?

Comment: In the general case I would say the "straightforward" (i.e. easy to think, but not super easy to implement) idea is to build on https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Longest_common_subsequence_problem algorithm, modify it slightly to return all the different variants for each word/token, and run it iteratively for `n-1` times.

Comment: You are asking the reader to infer a set of rules from an example. That's no good. You must specify a complete and precise set of rules. That is, you must provide a *specification*, which is a fundamental part of all computer programming. In real life, if you write a vague or incomplete specification, there will be blood on the floor.

Comment: Thanks @kfx I'll have a look at the wikipedia link.

Comment: @CarySwoveland you are right I will revise - although in questions of algorithms identifying the rules is most of the battle.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a more general solution:

```
# try to sync a list of strings by finding "sections" of identical words

# maximum lookahead (in case of nonidentical words)
MAX_DIFF = 5

# generate all possibilities to increase one position in the index array 
# in/out: array of index arrays
def inc_some(arrs)
  out = []
  for i in 0..arrs[0].size-1 do
    # increase i-th position
    arrs.each do |a|
      b = a.clone
      b[i] += 1
      out << b
    end
  end
  out
end

# is a given index array a match, i.e. a "section" of identical words?    
def matches(sens,a)
  sens.zip(a).map do |sen,offs|
    if sen then sen[offs] else "" end
  end.uniq.size == 1
end

# find a match    
def find_match(sens)
  len = sens.size
  # successively try more lookahead
  for m in 0..MAX_DIFF*len do
    arrs = [[0] * len] # start with current words
    # generate all possibilities to distribute a lookahead of m
    # among the word lists
    for i in 1..m do
      arrs = inc_some(arrs)
    end
    arrs.each do |a|
      # stop search if a match has been found
      if matches(sens,a)
        return a
      end
    end
  end
  # no match has been found
  return nil
end

# try to synchronise recursively    
def sync1(sens,acc)
  if sens.join("").empty?
    return {:ok => acc}
  end
  m = find_match(sens)
  # no match found? Then we only have a partial solution
  if m.nil? 
    return {:partial_solution => acc}
  end
  # pair word lists with match
  m = sens.zip(m)
  # if we found an immediate match, consume it
  # otherwise, consume only the *differing* words
  singleton = if m.map{|a| a[1]}.max == 0 then 1 else 0 end
  words = m.map do |s,offs|
    if s.nil? then "" else s[0,offs+singleton].join(" ") end
  end
  sens1 = m.map do |s,offs|
    if s.nil? then [] else s[offs+singleton,s.size] end
  end
  sync1(sens1,acc << words.uniq)
end

# synchronise a list of sentences    
def sync(sens)
  sync1(sens.map{|s| s.split(" ")},[])
end

sentences = [ 
  "News update I read a Jones, near record snowfalls...",
  "News update I'm Rita Jones, near record snowfalls...",
  "News update I am Rita Jones, near record snow-falls..."
]

puts sync(sentences).inspect

#> [["News"], ["update"], ["I read a", "I'm Rita", "I am Rita"], ["Jones,"], ["near"], ["record"], ["snowfalls...", "snow-falls..."]]
```

Comment: Accepted answer - this has worked perfectly with ever examples I've thrown at it.

Answer (score 1):

I took the bait here even though this clearly looks like homework.  The trick here is knowing what can be 'grouped' and what can't be grouped.  You didn't list instructions on that note so I assume it's open to interpretation.

```
sentences = [
  "News update I read a Jones, near record snowfalls...",
  "News update I'm Rita Jones, near record snowfalls...",
  "News update I am Rita Jones, near record snow-balls..."
]

@small_words = %w(a am)
def push_together(words)
  new_words = []
  words.each_with_index do |word, i|
    if @small_words.include?(word)
      new_words[i-1] += " " + word
    else
      new_words << word
    end
  end
  new_words
end

def words_in_sentences(sentences)
  new_sentences = []
  sentences.each do |sentence|
    words = sentence.split(" ")
    new_sentences << if words.any? { |w| @small_words.include?(w) }
                       push_together(words)
                     else
                       words
                     end
  end
  new_sentences
end

new_sentences = words_in_sentences(sentences)

grouped_words = []
new_sentences.each do |sentence|
  sentence.size.times do |i|
    grouped_words[i] ||= []
    grouped_words[i] << sentence[i]
  end
end

p grouped_words.map(&:uniq)
```

Output:

```
[["News"], ["update"], ["I", "I'm", "I am"], ["read a", "Rita"], ["Jones,"], ["near"], ["record"], ["snowfalls...", "snow-balls..."]]
```

Comment: This solution makes some very specific assumptions about "small words". Is the list of "small words" known beforehand?

Comment: That's a very fair comment @tillmo - I mention that what I'm grouping based on the pattern he mentions above but this is not an all encompassing solution by any stretch.

Comment: Thanks @Anthony but the text could contain many short words that could not be grouped together.

Comment: @WezWazzo - I think if you can answer 'when to group' short words together then you can simply adapt my solution to it.